# Combine two lists into a dictionary with (key, value) format?

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook example:

```
- name: Playbook
  hosts: server
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Set server hosts fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        k3s_server_hosts: "{{ groups['server'] }}"

    - name: Set server ips fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        k3s_server_ips: "{{ k3s_server_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) }}"

    - name: Debug
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: k3s_server_ips
```

Output:

```
TASK [Debug] ************
ok: [apollo] =>
  k3s_server_ips:
  - 192.168.4.2
  - 192.168.4.3
  - 192.168.4.4
ok: [boreas] =>
  k3s_server_ips:
  - 192.168.4.2
  - 192.168.4.3
  - 192.168.4.4
ok: [cerus] =>
  k3s_server_ips:
  - 192.168.4.2
  - 192.168.4.3
  - 192.168.4.4
```

My goal is to obtain the following format:

```
ok: [apollo] =>
  k3s_server:
  - name: apollo
    ip: 192.168.4.2
  - name: boreas
    ip: 192.168.4.3
  - name: cerus
    ip: 192.168.4.4
```

So I can use a list of either `name` or `ip` based list into various locations, for example something like `map('extract', k3s_server, 'name')` should produce a list of server names.

My goal is to use the fact into an Ansible template loop, please ignore the templating errors, this is just an example for expected logic:

```
{% for items in k3s_server %}
    server items['name'] items['ip']:6443 check
{% endfor %}
```

Which should produce a result like:

```
    server apollo 192.168.4.2:6443 check
    server boreas 192.168.4.3:6443 check
    server cerus 192.168.4.4:6443 check
```

However, if there is way to combine into Ansible template loop `k3s_server_hosts` and `k3s_server_ips` facts, this will be a satisfactory outcome also.

For example, the following template format produces the expected result:

```
{% for name, ip in k3s_server_hosts | zip(k3s_server_ips) %}
    server {{ name }} {{ ip }}:6443 check
{% endfor %}
```

```
TASK [Show templating results] ********
ok: [apollo] =>
  msg: |2-
        server apollo 192.168.4.2:6443 check
        server boreas 192.168.4.3:6443 check
        server cerus 192.168.4.4:6443 check
ok: [boreas] =>
  msg: |2-
        server apollo 192.168.4.2:6443 check
        server boreas 192.168.4.3:6443 check
        server cerus 192.168.4.4:6443 check
ok: [cerus] =>
  msg: |2-
        server apollo 192.168.4.2:6443 check
        server boreas 192.168.4.3:6443 check
        server cerus 192.168.4.4:6443 check
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do the above. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) and create a dictionary

```yaml
  k3s_server_dict: "{{ dict(k3s_server_hosts|zip(k3s_server_ips)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  k3s_server_dict:
    apollo: 192.168.4.2
    boreas: 192.168.4.3
    cerus: 192.168.4.4
```

Convert the dictionary to a list

```yaml
  k3s_server: "{{ k3s_server_dict|
                  dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='ip') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  k3s_server:
    - {ip: 192.168.4.2, name: apollo}
    - {ip: 192.168.4.3, name: boreas}
    - {ip: 192.168.4.4, name: cerus}
```

The below template

```yaml
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {% for item in k3s_server %}
              server {{ item.name }} {{ item.ip }}:6443 check
              {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    server apollo 192.168.4.2:6443 check
    server boreas 192.168.4.3:6443 check
    server cerus 192.168.4.4:6443 check
```

It's easier to use the dictionary instead of the list. The below template gives the same result

```yaml
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {% for k,v in k3s_server_dict.items() %}
              server {{ k }} {{ v }}:6443 check
              {% endfor %}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: server
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    k3s_server_hosts: "{{ groups.server }}"
    k3s_server_ips: "{{ k3s_server_hosts
                        |map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) }}"
    k3s_server_dict: "{{ dict(k3s_server_hosts|zip(k3s_server_ips)) }}"
    k3s_server: "{{ k3s_server_dict
                    |dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='ip') }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: k3s_server_dict
        - debug:
            var: k3s_server|to_yaml
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {% for k,v in k3s_server_dict.items() %}
              server {{ k }} {{ v }}:6443 check
              {% endfor %}
        - debug:
            msg: |
              {% for item in k3s_server %}
              server {{ item.name }} {{ item.ip }}:6443 check
              {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

Note: The variable *ansible_default_ipv4* depends on the OS. For example, the dictionary is empty in FreeBSD:

```yaml
  ansible_default_ipv4: {}
```

Instead, the list *ansible_all_ipv4_addresses* keeps all IPv4 addresses of a host. Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[server]
apollo ansible_host=test_01
boreas ansible_host=test_02
cerus ansible_host=test_03

[server:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=true
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

the below playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    server_hosts: "{{ groups.server }}"
    server_ips: "{{ server_hosts
                    |map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses')
                    |map('first') }}"
    server_dict: "{{ dict(server_hosts|zip(server_ips)) }}"
    server: "{{ server_dict|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='ip') }}"

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: default_ipv4

    - debug:
        var: ansible_default_ipv4
    - debug:
        var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: server_hosts
        - debug:
            var: server_ips
        - debug:
            var: server_dict
        - debug:
            var: server
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [apollo] => 
  ansible_default_ipv4: {}
ok: [boreas] => 
  ansible_default_ipv4: {}
ok: [cerus] => 
  ansible_default_ipv4: {}

ok: [apollo] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses:
  - 10.1.0.51
ok: [boreas] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses:
  - 10.1.0.52
ok: [cerus] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses:
  - 10.1.0.53

  server_hosts: [apollo, boreas, cerus]
  server_ips: [10.1.0.51, 10.1.0.52, 10.1.0.53]
  server_dict:
    apollo: 10.1.0.51
    boreas: 10.1.0.52
    cerus: 10.1.0.53
  server:
    - {ip: 10.1.0.51, name: apollo}
    - {ip: 10.1.0.52, name: boreas}
    - {ip: 10.1.0.53, name: cerus}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can build a list of `{'name': ..., 'ip': ...}` dictionaries with a looping task like this:

```
    - name: Set server ips fact
      vars:
        k3s_server_ips: []
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        k3s_server_ips: >
          {{
            k3s_server_ips + [
              {'name': item, 'ip': hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address}
            ]
          }}
      loop: "{{ groups.server }}"

    - name: Debug
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: k3s_server_ips
```

Which given a three-node example inventory produces output like:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "k3s_server_ips": [
        {
            "ip": "172.17.0.2",
            "name": "node-0"
        },
        {
            "ip": "172.17.0.3",
            "name": "node-1"
        },
        {
            "ip": "172.17.0.4",
            "name": "node-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

You could use a template rather than a looping task to accomplish the same thing:

```
    - name: Set server ips fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        k3s_server_ips: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for host in groups.server %}
          - name: {{ host }}
            ip: {{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
```